# Writing a simple find function without using some and every separately

Tags: javascript, function

I want to create a simple find function that finds an object in an `array` if the `key` in `value` matches one of its `keys`:

```
find(
  [ { name:'1', value:'a'}, { name:'2', value:'b' } ],
  { name:'1' }
) // => { name:'1', value:'a'}
```

If `value` has more than two `keys` then the `object` in the `array` has to match exactly:

```
find(
  [ { name:'1', value:'a'}, { name:'2', value:'b' } ],
  { name:'1', value:'b' }
) // => null
```

I know how to do this but by using `some` and `every` separately:

```
const keys = (object) => {
  return Object.keys(object)
}

const find = (array, value) => {
  return array.filter(object => {
    return keys(object).every(key => { // change this to .some
      return object[key] === value[key]
    })
  })[0]
}
```

Is there a way to write this without me having to swap `every` with `some` and vice versa?

Comment: Looks simple already. Just not backward compatible.

Comment: I've read this question a few times and I'm still confused as to what you're trying to ask here

Comment: @NickZuber using `some` accomplished the first functionality. Using `every` the second. I want a function that does both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to swap `object` with `value`, not `every` with `some`:

```
function find(array, value) {
  return array.find(object =>
    Object.keys(value).every(key =>
//                     ^^^^^
      object[key] === value[key]
    )
  );
}
```

This will work for both your cases, as it tests for `value` to be a subset of the properties in the respective `object`.

Comment: I can't believe the answer was so simple. Thanks! I'll accept your answer after some minutes.